# wget crawling search results of news website

Tags: download, search, wget

I am trying to crawl the search results of a news website using **wget**.

The name of the website is **www.voanews.com**.

After typing in my **search keyword** and clicking search, it proceeds to the results. Then i can specify a **"to" and a "from"-date** and hit search again.

After this the URL becomes:

```
http://www.voanews.com/search/?st=article&k=mykeyword&df=10%2F01%2F2013&dt=09%2F20%2F2013&ob=dt#article
```

and the actual content of the results is what i want to download.

To achieve this I created the following wget-command:

```
wget --reject=js,txt,gif,jpeg,jpg \
     --accept=html \
     --user-agent=My-Browser \
     --recursive --level=2 \
     www.voanews.com/search/?st=article&k=germany&df=08%2F21%2F2013&dt=09%2F20%2F2013&ob=dt#article
```

Unfortunately, the crawler doesn't download the search results. It only gets into the upper link bar, which contains the "Home,USA,Africa,Asia,..." links and saves the articles they link to.

*It seems like he crawler doesn't check the search result links at all*.

**What am I doing wrong and how can I modify the wget command to download the results search list links (and of course the sites they link to) only ?**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per se... but using standard:

```
wget.exe -o logfile -r -l 2 http://www.voanews.com/search/?st=article&k=german&df=11%2F01%2F2013&dt=11%2F03%2F2013&ob=dt#article
```

Crawls all pages (and more). I would take out the user agent clause <s>and a `-np` parent directory exclusion.</s>

On a personal note... there are a lot of links in a single search (e.g. the tags) so you will get several clutter with standard recursion.

Comment: You striked out -np (--no-parent) because the actual articles are stored in the www.voanews.com/conents/ directory, which is a parent directory of the search result site. The only difference in your wget is that you use a logfile, do not specify a user-agent and have no accept respectively reject clause.  I dont think that this proceeds to the links of the search results...

Comment: I striked it mainly because in Windows I had some problems with that option... At any rate this command lead me to crawl the search results, albeit it took everything with it. My supposition is that this will work as you have written, if you take out the user agent.

Comment: It still only downloads the links (and their contents) of the "Home,USA,Africa,Asia,..."-Navigation bar. I guess i have to write a python script to get those results.